# VS2019 Intellisense fights me. Is there a way to at least make it work like VS2017?

Tags: visual-studio-2017, resharper, visual-studio-2019

This is a minor but constantly annoying problem I see in all versions of Visual Studio.  Unfortunately suddenly in VS2019, my previous workaround no longer works.  I'm trying to figure out what settings I can change (if any) to fix it.

I've always had VS set up to align XML attributes with the first element.  So every time I hit ENTER, I'm just at the exact right same horizontal spot.

So, for example, a Border element ends up looking aligned like this:

```
<Border x:Name="ContentBorder"
        Background="Transparent">   *** NICELY ALIGNED ***
```

But every time I hit ENTER to start a new attribute, the Intellisense doesn't popup until I type at least one character.  So if I hit SPACE to make it popup, I end up with an attribute indented by a space.

```
<Border x:Name="ContentBorder"
         Background="Transparent">  *** NOTE ONE SPACE INDENT (Grrrr....) ***
```

OK, annoying but in every previous version of VS, I can get around this easily:  I just hit backspace at the start of the new attribute and then type a space to get back to the right column.  That space makes the the Intellisense popup.  It is a very minor annoyance but at this point I do it without thinking.

Unfortunately this workaround doesn't work in VS2019.  Now when I backspace at the start of a new attribute, the cursor doesn't just go back one space, it jumps all the way back to the previous line where it was before I hit ENTER.

So now I have to click the right column and manually re-align it (or other, equally intrusive workarounds).

So I have two questions:

**Question #1:**  Is there a way to make the Intellisense popup when I start the attribute without typing anything?

**Question #2:**  Can I at least change some editor setting to make VS2019 work like VS2017 and make a backspace (after ENTER) be a backspace

I've tried comparing VS2019 and VS2017 editor settings side-by-side to see what's different but I can't find it.

(Note: I do have Resharper on these machines but disabling it has no effect on this behavior.  Still if there were a way to fix this with some Resharper setting, I'd go for it)

Answer (score 1):

Try using Ctrl+Space instead of space to invoke Intellisense.
If you still want to use backspace + space, go to `Extensions > ReSharper > Options > Editor > Editor Behavior` and set `Unindent on Backspace` to `Disable`.